# Copy current app to startup directory error

Tags: c#, startup

```
string program = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) +
                 System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup", program);
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]'

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes` takes `byte[]` as a second parameter but you provide `program` which is `string`. Do you have a byte array to write this file?

Comment: I don't think fixing the code will solve your problem. At least the title suggest you are trying to do something different. Can you explain what should happen?

Comment: It should copy this program to startup directory..

Comment: That's not what the startup directory is for. Create a shortcut.